# Ubuntu tomcat Server Configuration

Tags: server, apache2, webserver, xampp, tomcat

I have a web application deployed in tomcat server via tomcat manager.

So it gets by `ip-address:8080/AppName`. But I need to get like: `http://www.domain_name.com`. What should I do? I need to access tomcat manager also.

Comment: In link `ip-address:8080/AppName` AppName is folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also simply edit the `server.xml` file of Tomcat, and add a new `Connector` node with this configuration:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

This will allow you access the application as `http://www.domain_name.com/AppName`. If you would like to drop the `AppName` part, you can publish the application as a ROOT application.

---

For a website though, it is a good idea to use an Apache or an nginx server as a reverse proxy to Tomcat, and also use them for serving static content.

In this case, you do not need to use the software as a ROOT application, as you can proxy that part of the URL too.

Answer (score 2):

Please rename your `.war` file to `ROOT.war` and restart the server

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Apache proxy configuration, so Apache proxies everything on www.domainname.com to your Tomcat App.

Something like this in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost :80>
Servername www.domainname.com
ProxyPass/ http://ip-address:8080/AppName
ProxyPassReverse / http://ip-address:8080/AppName
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course you may need to enable proxy in Apache first and do basic configuration for Apache