# 403 with Tomcat manager

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, java, tomcat

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Tomcat version: 9

This my conf

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
<!--
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="^.*$" />
  -->
          <!-- i try this as well -->
<!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+" />  -->

</Context>
```

This is my `tomcat-users.xml`

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="admin"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>

    <user username="name" password="pwd" roles="admin,admin-gui,manager,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I browse http://ip:8080/manager/  **403 Access Denied**

I've seen these questions and their answers

- [403 Access Denied on tomcat Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072009/403-access-denied-on-tomcat-server)
- [Can't enter in Manager App tomcat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984344/cant-enter-in-manager-app-tomcat)
- [Ubuntu tomcat Server Configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693292/ubuntu-tomcat-server-configuration)

These questions from Stack Overflow

- [403 Access Denied on Tomcat 8 Manager App without prompting for user/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551166/403-access-denied-on-tomcat-8-manager-app-without-prompting-for-user-password)
- [403 Access Denied on Tomcat 8 Manager App without prompting for user/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551166/403-access-denied-on-tomcat-8-manager-app-without-prompting-for-user-password/39985366)
- [Apache Tomcat/8.5.3 Manager App 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172756/apache-tomcat-8-5-3-manager-app-403-error)
- [403 Access Denied in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080148/403-access-denied-in-tomcat)
- [403 Access Denied on tomcat 7 to access host manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942691/403-access-denied-on-tomcat-7-to-access-host-manager)

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

See [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232878/apache-tomcat-9-unable-to-access-manager-webapp)

There are TWO files `context.xml`

- in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/host-manager/META-INF`
- in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF`

Add comment at `<Valve` in these files.

In `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml` add:

```
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>

<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-script,admin-gui,manager-script,manager-gui,manager-status"/>
```

It works with TOMCAT 10.0.6 but I think it works for previous versions too.